# How to increase quantity without adding the same object again?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hapi

I am trying to build  backend for my cart with node.I want to create API's for the cart that adds product and increase quantity if the product id is same but can't figure out how to do this.
Thank you all in advance for helping me out.

This is my model:

```
module.exports = (mongoose) =>
    new mongoose.Schema(
    {
      userId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
      product: {
        productId: { type: Number, required: true },
        slug: { type: String, required: true },
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
      },
      options: [
        {
          optionId: { type: Number, required: true },
          optionTitle: { type: String, required: true },
          valueId: { type: Number, required: true },
          valueTitle: { type: String, required: true },
        },
      ],
      price: { type: Number, required: true },
      quantity: { type: Number, required: true, min: 1 },
    },
    { timestamps: true }
  );
```

and this is my service method:
In this method what can I do to increase the quantity rather than adding the same product again?

```
const db = require('../models');
const logger = require('../utils/logger');

const service = 'cart';
const tag = service + '.js';

module.exports = {
    addItem: async (payload, auth) => {
    try {
      const cartExist = await db.Cart.findOne({
        userId: auth.credentials.customerId,
      });
      if (!cartExist) {
        const cart = {
          userId: auth.credentials.customerId,
          product: payload.product,
          options: payload.options,
          price: payload.price,
          quantity: payload.quantity,
        };
        await db.Cart.create(cart);
        return { success: true, data: cart };
      } else {
        console.log('Quantity increased');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      logger.error(tag + ': add', error);

      return { success: false, data: error };
    }
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to change the way your Cart `Schema` is designed.
Every Cart can have many products so it is better to store in products info in an `array`. Each product can have a `quantity` key. So your Schema should look like this:

```
module.exports = (mongoose) =>
new mongoose.Schema(
{
  userId: { type: Number, required: true, unique: true },
  products: [{
    productId: { type: Number, required: true },
    slug: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: true },
    quantity : {type : Number , required : true, default : 1 , min : 1}
  }],
  options: [  
    {
      optionId: { type: Number, required: true },
      optionTitle: { type: String, required: true },
      valueId: { type: Number, required: true },
      valueTitle: { type: String, required: true },
    },
  ],
  price: { type: Number, required: true },
},
{ timestamps: true }
);
```

In the service method, you can check if the `payload.product._id` is already in the cart's products, if yes, then you can simply change the quantity of that particular product.